# passing and returning results of a stored procedure executing in a JRXML to a java class

Tags: java, stored-procedures, lucene, jasper-reports

I have a scenario where i am using an Stored Procedure in a JRXML to generate the report. Now some of the data needs to be fetched from XML using Lucene search, all the data needs to be combined and be used for generating the Jasper Report.

My question is, is there a way to execute a Stored Procedure and send the results to a java class, which modifies the results and sends them back to JRXML to generate the desired report?. Other possible solutions are not feasible due to architectural patterns. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Mihir Pandya.

Comment: @Mihir: Not allowed to use a custom Java object to call the Stored Procedure?

Comment: Yes Dave, Cant use a custom java object to call the SP. SP call has to be in the JRXML